# Adding and removing forms in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I currently have the following code which adds a new input box everytime the user clicks a button. Is there a way to create a button to remove the last generated input box?

```js
var data = '<label>Temperature (K):</label><input type="number" name="temp"/>'


function addNew() {
  var newContent = document.createElement('div');
  newContent.innerHTML = data;
  document.getElementById('target').appendChild(newContent);
}
```

```html
<div id="target"></div>

<input id="add" type="button" value="Add New" onclick="addNew()" />
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild

Comment: I'd wrap the input and label in a div with a class, then find the last instance of that class and remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add:

```
<input id="remove" type="button" value="Remove last element" onclick="removeLastElem()" />
```

And:

```
function removeLastElem() {
    document.getElementById('target').lastChild.remove()
}
```

[EXAMPLE](https://jsfiddle.net/hoyajtzc/7/) :)

Answer (score 1):

Push your inputs into an array:

```
inputs=[];

inputs.push(newContent);
//put this in your addNew function
```

Now you can get the last element out of that array and remove it

```
function remove(){
if(inputs.length>0){
elem=inputs.pop();
elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
}
}
```

Comment: This will throw an error if the inputs length is 0.

Answer (score 0):

Put all the content you add to the form in a wrapping node:

```
var data = '<span><label>Temperature (K):</label><input type="number" name="temp"/></span>'
```

You can remove the last child of your "target" node:

```
function removeLast() {
    document.getElementById("target").lastChild.remove();
}
```

Comment: Can't you wrap it in a container node like: var data = '<span><label>Temperature (K):</label><input type="number" name="temp"/></span>'.

Comment: Yes shure, but you may need to describe it in your answer

Answer (score 0):

Here is sample of your java-script to remove added `div`

First you need to create button to remove newly added row 
and onclick you need to remove its parent element(last added div).

```
 var data='<label>Temperature (K):</label><input type="number" name="temp"/> <input type="button" value="Remove" onclick="removeDiv(this)"  />';


function addNew() {
   var newContent = document.createElement('div');
  newContent.innerHTML = data;
  document.getElementById('target').appendChild(newContent);
  }

function removeDiv(args){
args.parentNode.remove()
}
```

Sample [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/xajupudega/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score 0):

Just keep a list of added elements :

```js
var data = '<label>Temperature (K):</label><input type="number" name="temp"/>'

var addedList = []; 
function addNew() {
  var newContent = document.createElement('div');
  newContent.innerHTML = data;
  addedList.push(document.getElementById('target').appendChild(newContent));
}
function removeLast() {
    if (addedList.length) {
        document.getElementById('target').removeChild(addedList.pop());
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="target"></div>

<input id="add" type="button" value="Add New" onclick="addNew()" />
<input id="remove" type="button" value="Remove last added" onclick="removeLast()" />
```

If you just want the last element and not a list :

```js
var data = '<label>Temperature (K):</label><input type="number" name="temp"/>'

var addedEl = null; 
function addNew() {
  var newContent = document.createElement('div');
  newContent.innerHTML = data;
  addedEl = document.getElementById('target').appendChild(newContent);
}
function removeLast() {
    if (null !== addedEl) {
        document.getElementById('target').removeChild(addedEl);
        addedEl = null;
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="target"></div>

<input id="add" type="button" value="Add New" onclick="addNew()" />
<input id="remove" type="button" value="Remove last added" onclick="removeLast()" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple select last child and remove it

```
function removeLast(){
 document.getElementById("target").lastChild.remove(); 
}
```

Here is jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/aqev0pu4/

Answer (score 0):

Keep track of last inserted input tag with a counter as sub-string of its id and remove the last one by reading the id using counter.

```js
var inputCounter = 1;

function addNew() {
 var data = '<label>Temperature (K):</label><input type="number" id="counter' + inputCounter + '" name="temp"/>';
 inputCounter++;

 var newContent = document.createElement('div');
 newContent.innerHTML = data;
 document.getElementById('target').appendChild(newContent);
}

function removeLast() {
 if (inputCounter > 1) {
  inputCounter--;
  var last = document.getElementById("counter" + inputCounter).parentElement;
  document.getElementById('target').removeChild(last);
 } else {
  alert("Add new inputs. No last inserted input found.")
 }
}
```

```html
<div id="target"></div>

<input id="add" type="button" value="Add New" onclick="addNew()" />
<input id="remove" type="button" value="Remove last added" onclick="removeLast()" />
```